# How to get WOEID without using yahoo services?

Tags: ios, iphone, yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

Is there any other alternative to get WOEID of a place, other than yahoo services? Is there any third party library which is free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by making a query request using the city name you want and hitting yahoo service with code like this:

```
NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text=\"%@\"&format=xml", cityName];
NSString *encRequest = [request stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:encRequest];
```

I've put the complete example for this in [github](https://github.com/psy2k/YahooWeatherXMLParser), but this is a solution just for **testing** purposes. You should use the official way (and pay if needed) for a commercial app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above answer. So using yahoo services is the only way to go. Is there any other service, other than yahoo?

Comment: No there isn't. Actually WOEID is an id created by Yahoo itself http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOEID

Comment: That's actually not *completely* true. The database is published under a Creative Commons license and exists on archive.org: http://archive.org/search.php?query=geoplanet
It would not be impossible to build something out of that.